# What is the best way to see if a [time length] is available with rows of reservations?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, datetime

I have the following SQL table columns:

```
reservationId - int
startDateTime - datetime
endDateTime - datetime
```

**My issue is this:**

I want to see if there is a [time] period on a day when I can fit a [time] reservation.

For example, I'm looking for a 2 hour reservation on June 1st from 9am to 9pm.

June 1st currently has two reservations:

```
10am - 2pm
4pm - 6pm
```

I would want my query return the times available to make the reservation. Ie:

```
2pm - 4pm
6pm - 8pm
7pm - 9pm
```

Any ideas on how to go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have a window on when reservations can be made? As a note, this can often be easier if you have a separate `DATE` column that can be used for filtering prior to looking for conflicts. It can be indexed and makes it easier for MySQL to compute overlapping times. This doesn't work if your appointments can spill over into the next day, though.

Comment: @tadman yes, in the example it is June 1st, 9am -9pm. But this window will vary.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Why 06:00 to 09:00 and 07:00 to 09:00 but not 6:30 to 9:30 etc?

Comment: @stickybit just looking to check every top of the hour

Comment: 5.6.32 - MySQL Version @Uueerdo

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete answer, but it should get you halfway there:

```
SELECT o.openingStart, IFNULL(o.openingEnd, '2019-04-26 21:00:00') AS openingEnd
FROM (
    SELECT r.endDateTime AS openingStart
        , (SELECT r2.startDateTime 
           FROM reservations AS r2 
           WHERE r2.startDateTime > r.endDateTime
               AND r2.endDateTime < '2019-04-27 00:00:00'
           ORDER BY r2.startDateTime ASC
           LIMIT 1
        ) AS openingEnd
    FROM ( SELECT startDateTime, endDateTime 
           FROM reservations 
           WHERE startDateTime >= '2019-04-26 00:00:00' 
             AND endDateTime < '2019-04-27 00:00:00'
           UNION
           SELECT '2019-04-26 00:00:00', '2019-04-26 09:00:00'
         ) AS r
) AS o
```

Following this, you'd want to filter by only openings two hours or longer, and then probably need to join to some sort of static table of hours to expand larger openings into the smaller ones they can accommodate.

The IFNULL can actually be used in the inner query, but I thought it might be a little clearer like that.

Note: All the literal datetime values in there should be replaceable with appropriately calculated parameter values.